# Saving photo modified by PIL - Python 3+ Django 2+

Tags: django, python-imaging-library

I am trying to save my photo recive from my form changed by PIL in the ImageField field.

```
file = cd['custom_img'] #get my file from my form
#resize image
image = Image.open(file)
(w, h) = image.size
if (w > 1000):
    h = int(h * 1000. / w)
    w = 1000
image = image.resize((w, h), Image.ANTIALIAS)
rgb_image = image.convert('RGB')
#save in object
thumb_io = BytesIO()  #create a BytesIO object
rgb_image.save(thumb_io, 'JPEG', quality=80) # save image to BytesIO object
thumbnail = File(thumb_io) #create a django friendly File object
owner.basic_img = thumbnail
owner.save()
```

My code does not return any result. Nothing is still written in my field.

**My attempts:**

1.) Checking if the file will be saved
I tried to check if my picture was saved correctly. Everything works well. A modified photo is created from the form sent.

```
#resize image
print(file)
image = Image.open(file)
print(image)
(w, h) = image.size
if (w > 1000):
    h = int(h * 1000. / w)
    w = 1000
image = image.resize((w, h), Image.ANTIALIAS)
rgb_image = image.convert('RGB')
#save
rgb_image.save('my_image.jpg')
```

2.) I tried to save the photo according to this [tutorial](https://bhch.github.io/posts/2018/12/django-how-to-editmanipulate-uploaded-images-on-the-fly-before-saving/)

```
thumbnail = File(thumb_io, name=image.name) # create a django friendly File object
```

My code raises an error here

```
AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'name'
```

How can I save my resize image by PIL in my view?